# Error in faiss::Index* faiss::read_index(faiss::IOReader*, int) : Index type 0x73726576 ("vers") not recognized

Tags: flutter, faiss

Error:
Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'faiss::FaissException'
what(): Error in faiss::Index* faiss::read_index(faiss::IOReader*, int) at ../faiss/faiss/impl/index_read.cpp:793: Index type 0x73726576 ("vers") not recognized

Platform: Linux
OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Faiss version: 1.7.2

Installed from: Source

Faiss compilation options: cmake -B build -DBUILD_TESTING=ON -DFAISS_ENABLE_GPU=OFF -DFAISS_ENABLE_C_API=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release

I did try build from source, from release package, check version 1.7.1 -> 1.7.3 and still has error.

Comment: What source are you trying to build?

Comment: https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss i did build from this repository

Answer (score 0):

You can change the method of installation using either Conda or Conda Forge. Execute the following command:

```
$ conda install -c pytorch faiss-cpu=1.7.4 mkl=2021 blas=1.0=mkl
```

Alternatively, for Conda Forge, use this command:

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge faiss-cpu
```

For a more streamlined approach, consider creating a Dockerfile similar to the one outlined below:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

RUN apt-get install make

# install faiss for cpu use
RUN conda install faiss-cpu -c pytorch
```

By following these steps, you can install Faiss and its necessary dependencies efficiently, thereby ensuring smooth and hassle-free execution.